# Changing CSS of dynamically created Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring

I am facing this alignment issue with my flow diagram.
I have various stages which I pick from DB and depending upon various criteria I create the div and put it at its `absolute` position on screen.

**PROBLEM:** The issue at this point is, I am designing this for smaller screen (width = 1280px) but if user sees the site on larger screen, it comes to left due to the absolute layout. I want the diagram to the center always, so fixing the `left` property is one solution.

So I needed a logic to fix the css, i.e. `"left"` property dynamically depending upon the size of the screen.

So far I achieved this, but its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textFromController = [[${divText}]];
    $('.container').append(textFromController);
     var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 
     if(windowWidth > 1280){
         $(".item").css("left",  $(".item").css("left") + (windowWidth - 1280)/2);
     }
});
```

[image: Display of boxes with co-ordinates]

I am doing all the calculations on controller side so I cannot actually do anything there. I tried AJAX as well but then there is wastage of 1 call as I have to reload the full page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Media queries not helping you with this? you dont need to do this using javascript

Comment: @Sai the positioning is absolute so I am not sure how that will help. then I have to create 2 or 3 different set of diagrams. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: this can be solved with pure CSS, just work on your bigger screen, and resize the window to see how it behaves on a smaller screen

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/an-introduction-to-css3-media-queries.html#fbid=8UiSgdt_tX9       another: https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/   in short just google media queries. Basically Media queries does the job of finding out the width of your viewport and applies CSS styles that is specified for that specific width size

Comment: What's this `[[${divText}]]`? Never seen this kind of syntax...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Its thymeleaf. Was just showing smaller portion of the HTML. Sorry for that.

Comment: You should just get a wrapper div. position:relative; width:100%;margin:0 auto;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/L4L7aj5t/  is this something of an idea you were looking for?

Comment: @Sai: Yes, as you can see, I have a `container` which I am setting these `div` elements. So as they are not in DOM, I cannot use `.css()` on them. So was asking a way around it.

Comment: In my fiddle, I have made use of the media queries. So basically set the style you want for the `container` with the respective viewport width regardless if they are present in the DOM or not when the page loads. As and when it does get loaded, the style for that width gets applied.

Comment: Was this the solution you were looking for? If yes, I will post it as an answer

Comment: @Sai .. I tried your approach and its not coming properly. And the another question you asked, I have to pass top and left from controller coz the diagram is very big and static at this point. So I have to calculate everything and draw it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to center your diagram regardless of screen size then you can add this CSS to the `.item` instead of jQuery solution.

```
.item{
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0qcrqceg/1/)

Comment: I am sending the `top` and `left` for each `div` from controller, so I dont know how this will work.

Comment: @ADi Maybe I'm just not understanding your jQuery. I removed the `top` from the CSS and updated the fiddle. I figured you could just scrap the `windowWidth` jQuery variable portion of your code and apply it to your `.item`

Comment: do you have to have the top and left values sent from controller?